# What methods should I use from PythonCyc API to query metabolites in BioCyc database?

Tags: python, lisp, bioinformatics, biopython

I am using **PythonCyc** API in order to write a query for metabolites in **BioCyc**. The purpose of this API is to communicate with the database software of BioCyc- Pathway Tools. Pathway Tools is in lisp therefore, PythonCyc creates a bridge between python and common lisp. To use this this API one must first create a PGDB object with a specified organism ID (orgid). In the example below I create a PGDB with orgid "meta". After this, I am able to call methods from PythonCyc with this object:

```
import sys
import pythoncyc
#this creates PGDB object associated with meta(MetaCyc)
meta = pythoncyc.select_organism('meta')
#lists pathways of specified compound
pathways = meta.pathways_of_compound('sucrose')
print pathways
```

The query for the metabolite above, 'sucrose', provides a list a pathways:

```
[u'|PWY-7347|', u'|SUCSYN-PWY|', u'|PWY-7238|', u'|PWY-6527|', u'|PWY-5343|', u'|PWY-3801|', u'|PWY-7345|', u'|PWY-862|', u'|SUCUTIL-PWY|', u'|PWY66-373|', u'|PWY-621|', u'|PWY-822|', u'|SUCROSEUTIL2-PWY|', u'|PWY-6525|', u'|PWY-6524|', u'|PWY-5337|', u'|PWY-5384|']
```

However if I switch this metabolite name to a common amino acid name, such as 'valine':

```
import sys
import pythoncyc
#this creates PGDB object associated with meta(MetaCyc)
meta = pythoncyc.select_organism('meta')
#lists pathways of specified compound
pathways = meta.pathways_of_compound('valine')
print pathways
```

The query provides an error message that states "non coercible frame", which means it cannot find this ID. This is a common metabolite, just as sucrose, which should very well have pathway entries in database, however there are none found with this method. I have also tried synonyms of valine and other methods in PythonCyc such as "all_pathways(cpds)", which give me the same error message.
What is the reason for this? Does BioCyc not list any pathways for amino acids? Am I using an incorrect method to access amino acid information?

[Link to PythonCyc API](http://pythoncyc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Comment: Note that if you don't get satisfying answers here, you might try in the newly created bioinformatics SE site: https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Perhaps try the three-letter code for valine: `pathways = meta.pathways_of_compound('val')`

Comment: @bli thank you! I will repost it there

Comment: @nbryans I have tried that and unfortunately it did not work. I tried several different synonyms as well.